# Get all orders of customer by email id Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, sales-order, magento2.3, order-email

How can I get all orders of a customer via his/her email id who is logged in,
I am using current session to get user's email id

```
public function getCustomerData() {
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData();
    }
    return false;
}
```

In phtml

```
  $customerData = $block->getCustomerData();
  if($customerData) {
    echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerData->getEmail() . '<br/>'; }
```

Earlier I was getting my orders information by `order id`

```
public function getOrderInformation($orderid)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($orderid);
    return $order;
}
```

How can I get all orders by customer email id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

//*****************loading Customer session *****************//
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

//******** Checking whether customer is logged in or not ********//
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
$customer_email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();

// ***********Getting order collection using customer email id ***********//
 $order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email);

 //echo "<pre>";print_r($order_collection->getData());
 foreach ($order_collection as $order){ 
    echo "Order Id: ".$order->getEntityId(); 
    echo "Customer Id: ".$order->getCustomerId(); 
   } 
}
```

> Order collection based on logged in Customer Email Id (Customer All orders)

I hope this will help

Comment: how to get entity id and customer id from $order_collection->getData() my output is like this .       Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 166952
        )

)
customerid 12004 .  ,  what kind of format is this its not json for sure

Comment: i get this error . Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection::getEntityId()

Comment: foreach ($order_collection as $order){
           echo "Order Id: ".$order->getEntityId();
           echo "Customer Id: ".$order->getCustomerId();
     }   try this

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Orders;                                
class ReadOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
 \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
 \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerData()
{
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData()->getEmail();
    }
}
public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return;
    }
    $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $this->getCustomerData());
    foreach ($orders as $items) {
        echo $items->getCustomerEmail() . '<pre>';
    }
}}
```

Hope this help, if you need any other information. Let me know. 
Peace :)

Comment: Nice effort. +1